# Let A, B be open subsets of R. From the definition, prove that the intersection A ∩ B is also open.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Show that for any point x in the intersection A ∩ B, we can find a small interval (x − ε, x + ε) that is also contained in A ∩ B.

I am preparing for my mid-term test tomorrow and am stuck on a few questions. How would I be able to solve this one?

[I linked an image of what I have done so far, but I got stuck. How would I
continue and solve it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzk7X.png)

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In this case, an important context would be your definition of an open set.

Comment: @ElliotYu Didn't the OP supply this context via $(x - \epsilon, x+\epsilon)~?$

Comment: Hint: one of those $\varepsilon$s must be smaller than the other (or possibly the same).

Comment: Please edit your posting by removing the link to the image.  Instead, (also) edit your posting by using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to show all related Math.

Comment: @user2661923 I tried to, after your suggestion, but I couldn't get around to it as it's my first time on StackExchange. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set things up correctly. Can you visualize the intervals? What happens if you take $\epsilon=\min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$?

Comment: Thank you. I took the minimum. And wrote (x-ϵ, x+ϵ) subset of (x - ϵ1, x +ϵ1) subset of A. Then, I did something similar to B. 

Concluded that (x-ϵ, x+e) is a subset of A and B. Would this be right?

Comment: @MonibNiazi Yes, that's right.